# Using PHP to obtain page link and pass variables between pages

Tags: php

I am going to try and synthesize this as simply as possible. I have a checklist form. Once checked and submited, the checked items are diplayed as a div on the page. *I then want to email these checked items to me.*

I have two php files. 
The first is for the checkbox form. When things are checked and submitted it changes the URL:

```
 header("Location: galarieproject.php?s=".urlencode("You selected:" . " ").$passit."#checklist"); exit;
```

My second php file is supposed to email the checked items to me. However, when I submit the second form it says "Cannot modify header information."

I think this problem is arising because the email form attempts to change the URL upon submission, but the checkbox url is this long thing:

galarieproject.php?s=You+selected%3A+Cork%20Board%20Barn%20Door%20#checklist

and the email php attempts to change the url from a static url:

```
header("Location: galarieproject.php?d=".urlencode("Thank you for your donation.")); exit;
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I hope this makes some sense.

Comment: If you output anything to the page (echo, var_dump, etc.) you cannot modify the header afterwards. You should check if that is your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using $_Session variable

This website explains it in great detail:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I am still getting errors unfortunately. "headers already sent" is something I keep receiving when I try and change the url upon form submission

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ob_start()` on the very top of your email.php and in the end use `ob_flush()` . This will solve problem.